# Check constraint in master-detail

Tags: master-detail, unique

Is it possible to implement 1:1 relation between master and detail. I'm not able to create neither rollup summary on master nor trigger on detail

Comment: Why can you not create a RSF or trigger? Is it a self-imposed challenge, or is there a technical reason?

Comment: seems like a technical reason.i'm not sure that i can create new field. Trigger might  be as alternative

Comment: wouldn't rise a new topic so - seems like we may use duplicate rules. Are there some restrictions?

Comment: Duplicate rules sounds like it should be possible.

Comment: not so. as i found out - they need at least more than one field. `Error: We can't save this matching rule because it uses the Account lookup field Account Name without other Contact fields, which returns poor match results and inhibits performance. Please add at least one Contact field to the rule or modify the filter logic so the rule isn't matching on just Account Name.`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add more detail. Right now, it's very hard to follow what you are trying to do and what specific technical constraints you are struggling with.

Comment: As I said we cannot neither create new field on Account nor trigger on detail object. When it comes to duplicate rules - there is need to create at least 2 matching conditions. i'm gonna create formula field with AccountId copy in detail object and include it to duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but you seem to be referring to the account-contact relationship.  This is a lookup relationship, not master-detail.

One solution is to use a rollup tool such as the free [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Getting-Started-With-DLRS) to populate a count field on Account.  Then you can use a validation rule on contact to prevent creation of new records if the count is exceeded.

Comment: It isn't possible to install packages, unfortunately. My previous comment was incorrect regarding to duplicate rules error. We have master-detail between Account and details Object (not Contact)